# Configure IPTABLES to MASQUERADE traffic from a single host in lan and block other

Tags: iptables, masquerade

Have a proxy server with squid installed. Want to configure iptables so as to allow a single ip in lan to access internet directly without directing the traffic through squid.
the following works to masquerade traffic but how to filter so that only one ip is given access
**iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE**

the current iptables configuration is default. It does't have any rules applied.The squid server does its usual of providing proxy internet service.

currently i am studying iptables, so not a expert in it.So kindly be specific to rules that should be applied.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail on your iptables setup with regard to squid and masquerading.

Answer (score 0):

You have packets passing through your server, so you have to add rules to filter:FORWARD if you want to block transiting traffic. Probably you want this:

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD ! -s {SPECIFIC_IP_FROM_LAN} -j DROP
```

but **don't forget** to add rules that accept the rest of the transiting traffic before this rule. filter:FORWARD is used for both WAN -> LAN and LAN -> WAN.

Comment: i tried this but it did't work. Also please describe the rules that u mentioned above service iptables save;service iptables restart;service network restart.
Thanx